# Custom Text View and setText

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a custom Text View and set its text by applying some function to the passed value.

For example if my xml is:-

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_raptor_medium"
android:text="someText"/>
```

then I would want to take the someText; apply my transformation function to it and set the Text again. basically this will be my string Id for which I will fetch the translation from my function.

EDIT:-
so In my custom view class, I am overriding the set Text Method like this:-

```
@Inject
StringRepository stringRepository
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    System.out.println("In SetTExt Method");
    // modify text here
    System.out.println("The text that is set here is:" + text);
    String modifiedText = StringRepository.getString((String)text);
    super.setText(modifiedText, type);
}
```

Now the getString Method is giving a Null pointer exception as the map that it accesses is not getting updated.

I am updating this map during Login Time.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `TextView` class first and then override `setText()` method, where you can do all the transformations. Thats it.

It should look something like this:

```
class YouTextView extends TextView {
    public YouTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public YouTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public YouTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        // modify text here
        super.setText(modifiedText, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this worked but setText somehow is not invoked at runtime. My Map from which I require to fetch the translation is populated at runtime and when I try to get value from it for setting that gives me runtime NullPointer Exception that thr map is empty

Comment: Add more code where you are trying to set these translations and getting null

Comment: Added in description. Please check?

Comment: You need to initialise StringRepository I assume first. For that you can use context from constructor

Comment: please also share for Menu Item